# What is the confluent platform components service url on docker

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-cli

I have started confluent platform on windows with the help of docker. I am able to start Kafka Broker, Zookeeper & control center.

I have setup the `confluent-cli` as well in docker. Now when I try to run the commands on `confluent-cli`, it's expecting `--url` param. Confluent docs says that `Contact your IT admin to get the HTTP address for the <service url> (for example, http://127.0.0.1:8080/) for each Confluent Platform component`. Since I am running docker on my local now, what would be my service url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I have started `schema-registry` as well and I can use the `schema-registry` port to check the cluster details.

`confluent cluster describe --url http://<my_ip>:<schema_registry_port>`

I got the below output when I run the describe command

```
Scope:
           Type           |           ID
+-------------------------+------------------------+
  kafka-cluster           | d60cQ7BWQTSz5v9fNuvQRw
  schema-registry-cluster | schema-registry
```

Reference : https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/command-reference/confluent_cluster_describe.html#example